# Is it possible to deny a range of IP addess for a specific Web Site in IIS 7.0?

Tags: iis

I know there's options to deny access to the entire server but I am looking for do it for a specific Web Site.

I want to make sure just a couple of IP's are available to use a site.

Comment: Yes.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730889.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but If I am good, this is for the entire server. I am looking for a specific web sit.e

Comment: You can simply drill into the node for a specific website and do it there instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is it possible to deny a range of IP addess for a specific Web Site in IIS 7.0?**

Yes, you can do it for a whole site, or even a subdirectory.

You may need to install the IP security Windows Server Role Service (or Windows feature if you are not using Windows Server) to enable the functionality - it isn't installed by default.

See this link for how to enable it:
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity

The link also explains how to do what you want for a specific website, using the GUI.

But I prefer to use a `web.config` file. Place this file in the relevant site's directory root, or for subdirectory restrictions, place the `web.config` in that subdirectory.

```
<security>
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
        <clear/>
        <!--  allow single IP - e.g. localhost -->
        <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true"/>
        <!--  allow range -->
        <add ipAddress="10.10.10.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" allowed="true"/>
    </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

The above example contains `allowUnlisted="false"` and therefore denies access to all IPs other than the ones that are specifically added. The `<clear/>` directive prevents inheritance of `ipSecurity` settings from a higher level.